# Get back object from list by given id

Tags: c++, list

In order to implement Edmond's Cardinality Matching Algorithm in C++ I have created a new struct for vertecies of a graph, that stores some more information needed for the algorithm, and a function, that gets back the vertex by putting in its id. However, it does not do, what it is supposed to do.

I want the function getVertex(ED::NodeId x, std::list vertecies) to give back the vertex in the list vertecies with the id x (which is the first parameter v). The relevant code is the following:

```
struct vertex 
{
ED::NodeId v;
ED::NodeId m;
ED::NodeId f;
ED::NodeId r;
int scanned;
void setM(vertex neigh);
void setF(vertex neigh);
void setR(vertex neigh);
void setScanned(int scan);
} vrtex;


vertex getVertex(ED::NodeId x, std::list<vertex> vertecies)
{
for (std::list<vertex>::iterator it = vertecies.begin(); it!=vertecies.end(); ++it)
{
    if(it->v == x)
    {
        return (vertex) * it;
    }
}
printf("No element with id %i found.", x);

return createVertex(0); //If there is no suche node id in vertecies
```

}

If I plug in getVertex(vert.m, vertecies), I always get back the vertex vert, and not the vertex, that is indexed by vert.m, I feel, this has something to do with the pointer, I do not exactly understand what it does as I am new to C++. I am thankful for any help fixing my function.

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question, if you just want the index, you should have a (for int i loop) and return i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not actually get what your problem is. I run your code and get vertex back by index normally.
Here is code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

namespace ED
{
    typedef int NodeId;
}

struct vertex 
{
ED::NodeId v;
ED::NodeId m;
ED::NodeId f;
ED::NodeId r;
int scanned;
void setM(vertex neigh);
void setF(vertex neigh);
void setR(vertex neigh);
void setScanned(int scan);
} vrtex;


vertex getVertex(ED::NodeId x, std::list<vertex> vertecies)
{
    for (std::list<vertex>::iterator it = vertecies.begin(); it!=vertecies.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(it->v == x)
        {
            printf("Element found!\n");
            return (vertex) * it;
        }
    }
    printf("No element with id %i found.", x);

    return vertex(); // If there is no suche node id in vertecies
} 

int main()
{
    std::list<vertex> vertices = 
    {
        {0,0,0,0,0},
        {1,0,0,0,0},
        {2,0,0,0,228},
        {3,0,0,0,0}
    };

    printf("%d\n", vertices.size());

    vertex e = getVertex(2, vertices);
    printf("Element.scanned = %d\n", e.scanned);
    vertex vert = {0,2,0,0,0};
    e = getVertex(vert.m, vertices);
    printf("Element.scanned = %d\n", e.scanned);
}
```

And the output:

```
[DDRDmakar@localhost New Folder]$ g++ test.cpp && ./a.out
4
Element found!
Element.scanned = 228
Element found!
Element.scanned = 228
```

Maybe I use wrong types or arguments, but it works...
But it'll be better to use for-each loop. It works the same way but is much safer:

```
vertex getVertex(ED::NodeId x, std::list<vertex> vertecies)
{
    for (const auto &e : vertecies)
    {
        if(e.v == x)
        {
            printf("Element found!\n");
            return e;
        }
    }
    printf("No element with id %i found.", x);

    return vertex(); // If there is no suche node id in vertecies
}
```